# How do I connect to remote virtual machines on Virtual Box?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm new to Oracle Virtual box but have used VMware several times.

I have a client that is now running a Windows xp virtual machine on his main machine to access a piece of bespoke software that will not run on a newer OS than XP 32bit. He has another PC of which he would like to be able to access the virtual machine from.

Can this be achieved? Do I need to use bridge mode within virtual box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use bridged adapter on the virtual machine, set it up so the main pc, second pc and VM are on the same workgroup connect to the same switch or router and connect to the VM using remote desktop connection. Simple as that! Make sure RDP is enabled in the virtual machine aswell. You will login with the admin credentials from the VM.

Get the IP of the VM from command prompt using ipconfig /all
Use the VM will have its own IP assigned to it by your router or you can set it to be static.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved. VirtualBox offers this functionality:

> VirtualBox can display virtual machines remotely, meaning that a virtual machine can execute on one computer even though the machine will be displayed on a second computer, and the machine will be controlled from there as well, as if the virtual machine was running on that second computer.

([Chapter 7](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) of the official documentation)

From the same chapter:

> Oracle provides support for the VirtualBox Remote Display Protocol (VRDP) in such a VirtualBox extension package. When this package is installed, VirtualBox versions 4.0 and later support VRDP the same way as binary (non-open-source) versions of VirtualBox before 4.0 did.
>
> VRDP is a backwards-compatible extension to Microsoft's Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). As a result, you can use any standard RDP client to control the remote VM.

Finally, the documentation offers examples of how to connect to remote VMs on Windows and Linux:

> On Windows, you can use the Microsoft Terminal Services Connector
>   (`mstsc.exe`) that ships with Windows. You can start it by bringing up
>   the "Run" dialog (press the Windows key and "R") and typing "`mstsc`".
>   You can also find it under "Start" -> "All Programs" -> "Accessories"
>   -> "Remote Desktop Connection". If you use the "Run" dialog, you can type in options directly:
>
> ```
> mstsc 1.2.3.4:3389
> ```
>
> Replace `1.2.3.4` with the host IP address, and `3389` with a different
>   port if necessary.

And on Linux;

> you can use the standard open-source rdesktop program. This ships with
>   most Linux distributions, but VirtualBox also comes with a modified
>   variant of rdesktop for remote USB support (see Section 7.1.4, “Remote
>   USB” below).
>
> With `rdesktop`, use a command line such as the following:
>
> ```
> rdesktop -a 16 -N 1.2.3.4:3389
> ```